# Liferay Portal CE and EE

Tags: liferay, windows-ce, enterprise

Our company is developing e-portal solutions for the government in Vietnam. We are using Liferay Community Edition. We are considering switching to Enterprise Edition.

From a programmer's perspective, is there something LP EE can do that LP CE cannot (performance, security, functionality, etc.)? We would like to hear from the experiences of programmers who have worked with both LP CE and EE before.

Thank you so much.

Linh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what the others already mentioned, Liferay EE is supported for ~5 years after release, while you won't get upgrades for major CE versions once the next release is out - so you need to upgrade less often. Support includes patches for problems that you discover (on a service level) as well as cumulative fixpacks, typically more often than on CE.

For clustering - especially for bigger clusters - there are some additional clustering options in EE that optimize the cluster communication in order to scale better.

Liferay Sync can synchronize multiple document libraries on EE, compared to a single document library in CE

Liferay Developer Studio, the commercial extension of eclipse, works with more application servers - especially the "big iron" servers while the CE/Open Source version Liferay IDE works with the open source appservers/servletcontainers.

Plus, you're supporting further development of the product directly.

That being said, however you decide, please get involved in the [Liferay community](http://www.liferay.org) and help to make the product even better

Comment: Olaf, thank you for sharing your knowledge as a consultant. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That is no prommical question, but I can say that EE get early bugfixes and EE is altogether robustly that CE.

Comment: Thank you, Mark. Is there any critical feature for a portal that cannot be done in Liferay CE, but can be done in Liferay EE?

Comment: Not for me. Some more features for clustering with terracotta.

Answer (score 0):

Also, Liferay Portal EE has access to EE only marketplace applications, such as:

[Kaleo Workflow Designer](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15194706)

[Kaleo Workflow Forms](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15194452)

[Auditing portlet](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15195165)

[Reporting portlet](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15100467)

There may be more EE only applications but that is all I can think of right now.